# What is the diffference between the prefix and destdir params for dh_auto_install?

Tags: packaging, deb

I want to make my own debian package and I want to install it in `/opt/A/B/C`.

When overwriting `dh_auto_install` the documentation shows that you can use params `--destdir=` and `-- prefix=`.

If I want to install my debian contents to `/opt/A/B/C` do I specify this via

```
override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install -- prefix=/opt/A/B/C
```

OR

```
override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install --destdir=/opt/A/B/C
```

---

Notes: I plan on installing the deb onto Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Answer (score 5):

`dh_auto_install` only recognises `--destdir` as an option; when you write `-- prefix=...`, that’s not a `dh_auto_install` option, it’s an argument that’s passed on to whatever program `dh_auto_install` determines it needs to run in order to perform the installation.

However `dh_auto_install` is probably not the appropriate tool for what you’re trying to achieve. The final installation prefix is usually specified at configuration time, not at installation time; for that, you’d override `dh_auto_configure`:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- --prefix=/opt/A/B/C
```

Answer (score 2):

You should to know difference between **prefix** and **destination directory (destdir)**:

**prefix** - is path that prepend path to your binaries.

**destdir** - is location of your binaries.

Typically (the most popular way) workflow that produce binaries from source looks as follow (it's just example):

1. `./configure --prefix=/prepend/path ...`.
2. `make ...`.
3. `make install DESTDIR=/path/for/binaries`.

As you can see, **prefix** is set during configure step.

After step 3 files that were built will be installed in `/path/for/binaries` and will be located in `/path/for/binaries/prepend/path`.

When you build package, you have the directory with the sources and the `debian` directory in it.

If your program must be located in `/opt/A/B/C` you should override `dh_auto_configure` ([man 1 dh_auto_configure](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debhelper/dh_auto_configure.1.en.html)) target in `debian/rules` with follows:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- --prefix=/opt/A/B/C
```

This step correspond to step 1 that was mentioned at the begging of the answer.

Then, there is no need to override something else in the `debian/rules`.

---

@StephenKitt give good clarification about `dh_auto_install` in comments to this question.

Comment: `dh_auto_install` isn’t intended for what you’re describing; its only role is to run whatever command needs running to transform the build tree into an installation tree. When you build multiple packages, you use `dh_auto_install` as usual, without any per-package considerations; it realises there are multiple packages on its own and installs to `debian/tmp`. You then use `dh_install` (without `auto`) to install the files into the appropriate packages, typically using `.install` files rather than explicit `dh_install` invocations.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank's for clarify! I did mistake and will edit my answer.